# Post offline/without login using Facebook SDK PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need implement a functionality in save/update function, of my customers system: 
**In each save/update, I need get this informations, and send to a Facebook Page (every the same Page).**

But my problem is: this system is used by a lot users, and some users do not have a Facebook account, so: *How can I post in same Page without login?*

- I know the offline_access are removed, so, what the best solution in this situation?
- I don't find any way, to get the **Page Access Token**
- I create some APP in my personal account of Facebook, but, when I try post in this Page, I get a *access unauthorized for this user/app*

*Sorry for my english.*

Comment: I guess you want to post to a specific page, you can get the Page Access Token of the same and use it, it generally doesn't has any expiry or if that is not the case then you may use extended access token. Please clarify as to what you want to achieve.

Comment: @AnveshSaxena I do not know, how can I get this Page Access Token.

Answer (score 0):

For you to post updates on to the Page's feed there are few things you would require

1. An User with administrative or content publishing permission to atuhorize your application with `manage_pages` [Extended permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#overview). If you have implemented the login, you can add these permissions there, or alternatively you can use [Graph Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) with your application selected to get started.
2. After you have been authorized then you can retrieve the Page Access Token by querying `/me/accounts` which would return data as shown in this [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/). You can then utilize the access token you retrieve for the corresponding page to do your job of posting updates.

Comment: I'll test that. But, I dont know if you understand: the users cant login because not have any account.

Comment: Yup, I understood that part. I think you meant to say that these all post updates would be posted on this single page. You can just hard code the access token and use it as you please.